# Declined a meeting, but still getting updates

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, calendar

We have a weekly meeting, and an invite is sent to a very large group of participants, that can choose whether to attend or not.

I chose not to, so I declined the meeting. But now, every time the meeting time is changed, or an agenda is added to the invite, I get these updates and the meeting pops right back on my calendar.

How can I tell outlook that I do not want to participate in this meeting and do not want to receive any updates about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found that in outlook (I'm using 2010) there is an "Ignore" button in the delete section of the home toolbar. This will delete the conversation and automatically delete all future emails in this conversation.

This is the best I could find after quite some searching.